# jQuery: How to validate dimensions of images before upload?

Tags: jquery, image, validation, height, width

I have some problem with jquery. I found some solution to validate the size of an image before upload. It was posted also here:

```
$.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    // param = size (in bytes) 
    // element = element to validate (<input>)
    // value = value of the element (filename)
    return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param) 
});
```

I defined everything and it works perfectly! But i also would like to validate the width and height of that image. I tried to add a second method which is the same like above but instead of size I used height or width but this doesnt work:

```
$.validator.addMethod('widthpic', function(value, element, param) {
   return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].width == param) 
});
```

Is there any solution for this? Of course i also checked the size of the image in PHP but I would like to add that also in jquery-style.

Comment: http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/validation.html#image-validation

Answer (score 0):

The thing being leveraged to read the size of the file is the [W3C File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).  I don't see any reference there to suggest that you could determine something like the width or height.  You'd have to wait til the server-side, get the image and then use a library like [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) to check the dimensions.

Comment: Step 1: Turn the `File` into a Data URI.  Step 2: Set the `src` attribute of an `<img>` to this data URI.  Step 3: Check the image's width/height after handling the `onload` event.

Comment: @RayNicholus - cool, that sounds like it would work in general... but how does that help before they have uploaded the file (this is happening during validation pre-upload)

Comment: If you want to validate a user-submitted file, you must do so pre-upload.  I suspect you are confusing "upload" with choosing a file.  Once a file is uploading, its bytes are already being sent to the server.  Once the user drops or selects a file via a file input, you can do whatever you like to the file, provided the browser supports the File API.

Comment: @RayNicholus - So just to be clear, if the user selects a file, and then before submitting the form, the page triggers this `width` check, the File API allows you check the width as you suggested in your first comment?  Please add an answer if that's so, I'd upvote it! :)